# Hibernate and eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin, jboss-tools

I updated eclipse to the latest version, installed latest jboss tools hibernate, and the hibernate HQL editor stopped working. My webapp code is running fine though. Is there a way to fix this? currently installed jdk jdk-11.0.10

```
Exception Stack Trace:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractQueryFacade.list(AbstractQueryFacade.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HQLQueryPage.getList(HQLQueryPage.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer$ContentProviderImpl.getElements(QueryPageViewer.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getRawChildren(StructuredViewer.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getRawChildren(ColumnViewer.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTableViewer.java:1041)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getSortedChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTableViewer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1400)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1361)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1634)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.createTable(QueryPageViewer.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.createControl(QueryPageViewer.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.<init>(QueryPageViewer.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView.rebuild(QueryPageTabView.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView$1.contentsChanged(QueryPageTabView.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView$1.intervalAdded(QueryPageTabView.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalAdded(AbstractListModel.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.console.QueryPageModel.add(QueryPageModel.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.console.KnownConfigurations$1.queryPageCreated(KnownConfigurations.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.fireQueryPageCreated(ConsoleConfiguration.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.executeHQLQuery(ConsoleConfiguration.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.hqleditor.HQLEditor.executeQuery(HQLEditor.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.execute(ExecuteQueryAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.run(ExecuteQueryAction.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.runWithEvent(ExecuteQueryAction.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2304)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2057)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2019)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'product0_.product_category' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 82 more



-- Error Details --
Date: Sun Apr 04 20:23:40 CEST 2021
Message: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Severity: Error
Product: Eclipse IDE 4.19.0.20210311-1200 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product)
Plugin: org.hibernate.eclipse.console
Exception Stack Trace:
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2304)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2057)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2019)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractQueryFacade.list(AbstractQueryFacade.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HQLQueryPage.getList(HQLQueryPage.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer$ContentProviderImpl.getElements(QueryPageViewer.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getRawChildren(StructuredViewer.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getRawChildren(ColumnViewer.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTableViewer.java:1041)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getSortedChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTableViewer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1400)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1361)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1634)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.createTable(QueryPageViewer.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.createControl(QueryPageViewer.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.<init>(QueryPageViewer.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView.rebuild(QueryPageTabView.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView$1.contentsChanged(QueryPageTabView.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView$1.intervalAdded(QueryPageTabView.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalAdded(AbstractListModel.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.console.QueryPageModel.add(QueryPageModel.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.console.KnownConfigurations$1.queryPageCreated(KnownConfigurations.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.fireQueryPageCreated(ConsoleConfiguration.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.executeHQLQuery(ConsoleConfiguration.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.hqleditor.HQLEditor.executeQuery(HQLEditor.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.execute(ExecuteQueryAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.run(ExecuteQueryAction.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.runWithEvent(ExecuteQueryAction.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'product0_.product_category' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 82 more


-- Error Details --
Date: Sun Apr 04 20:23:40 CEST 2021
Message: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Severity: Error
Product: Eclipse IDE 4.19.0.20210311-1200 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product)
Plugin: org.hibernate.eclipse.console
Exception Stack Trace:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractQueryFacade.list(AbstractQueryFacade.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HQLQueryPage.getList(HQLQueryPage.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer$ContentProviderImpl.getElements(QueryPageViewer.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getRawChildren(StructuredViewer.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getRawChildren(ColumnViewer.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTableViewer.java:1041)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getSortedChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTableViewer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1400)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1361)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1634)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.createTable(QueryPageViewer.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.createControl(QueryPageViewer.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.<init>(QueryPageViewer.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView.rebuild(QueryPageTabView.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView$1.contentsChanged(QueryPageTabView.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView$1.intervalAdded(QueryPageTabView.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalAdded(AbstractListModel.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.console.QueryPageModel.add(QueryPageModel.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.console.KnownConfigurations$1.queryPageCreated(KnownConfigurations.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.fireQueryPageCreated(ConsoleConfiguration.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.executeHQLQuery(ConsoleConfiguration.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.hqleditor.HQLEditor.executeQuery(HQLEditor.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.execute(ExecuteQueryAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.run(ExecuteQueryAction.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.runWithEvent(ExecuteQueryAction.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2304)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2057)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2019)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'product0_.product_category' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 82 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an exact description of the following info:

- the version of Eclipse and JBoss Tools that you are using
- the version of Hibernate (ORM and Tools) that you are using
- the database (and version) that you are using

In addition, it would absolutely be helpful if you create a minimal project that exposes the problem and describe the different steps to reproduce the issue:

- creation of the Hibernate Console
- which HQL are you trying to execute from this console

Cheers,
Koen